# RavenDB Transformation - Exception thrown when trying to create a list of object

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm trying to run a RavenDB transformation to map my documents to view models, but I'm running into this error:

> Error CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1'

I'm not sure why I can't initialise the new list of OfferRate here. How can I map my document model to the view model correctly?

**Offer_ViewModel.cs**

```
public class Offer_ViewModel : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<Offer>
{
    public Offer_ViewModel()
    {
        TransformResults = offers => offers
            .Select(offer => new ViewModels.Offer
            {
                Id = offer.Id,
                MerchantId = offer.MerchantId,
                Title = offer.Title,
                OfferRates = new List<OfferRate>
                {
                  new OfferRate
                  {
                      Type = OfferRateType.Base,
                      Amount = offer.Amount,
                      Percentage = offer.Percentage
                  }  
                },
                Currency = offer.Currency
            });
    }
}
```

I'm following the guide to map to view models using transformers here: https://ravendb.net/articles/working-with-view-models but the example doesn't include mapping aggregated objects.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `                OfferRates = new []`?

Comment: This works, thank you @AyendeRahien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment above, changing the collection to an array works.

**Offer_ViewModel.cs**

```
public class Offer_ViewModel : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<Offer>
{
    public Offer_ViewModel()
    {
        TransformResults = offers => offers
            .Select(offer => new ViewModels.Offer
            {
                Id = offer.Id,
                MerchantId = offer.MerchantId,
                Title = offer.Title,
                OfferRates = new[]
                {
                  new OfferRate
                  {
                      Type = OfferRateType.Base,
                      Amount = offer.Amount,
                      Percentage = offer.Percentage
                  }  
                },
                Currency = offer.Currency
            });
    }
}
```